# Allow roles not working but allow users working in web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I implemented asp.net membership for forms authentication. Generally for login it is used **username**, but i changed this to login with **email id**. Which is working fine. Now i am trying to restrict access to the users which are not in **Admin** role. I created web.config file in that folder i written like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin" />
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When i tested with this one even though the users who is having the **admin** role is not able to access. When he clicks the link he is signing out (like the user doesn't have permission to access the page). For showing menu i am using **web.sitemap** file. It is working fine based on roles. 
Code in the web.cofnig file under that particular folder is correct as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I don't know why it is not working. If we change membership controls default login behavior then any thing should take care about roles?
Many questions to similar were found in stackoverflow as well as in some other sites also. But nothing gives me solution. Whats wrong in this? Need to write any custom code to handle? 
For allowing users i written like below. It is working **perfect**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="master@yahoo.com" />
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Why it is not working only for roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RoleProvider` use `GetRolesForUser` method to retrieves authorized roles for a user.

```
// Notice that it accept username instead of email
public string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
```

In your case, your `RoleProvider` passes `master@yahoo.com` as username. As the result, there is no username with `master@yahoo.com` in User table.

**Here are solutions -**

1) The easiest way to solve the problem is copy **Email** column of **Memberships** table to **UserName** column of **Users** table.

2) The hard way create custom `RoleProvider` and override `GetRolesForUser` method.

3) If you happen to use `legacy Membership Provider` instead of [Universal Membership Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx), you can modify **aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetRolesForUser**.

Answer (score 0):

I used another approach. I didn't changed the login with emailid. I am logging with email only. But problem is coming because by default, role provider verify with **user name** instead of **email**. For that i changed `login` behavior. So when ever user login i used to give the login control value like below.

```
 string username = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(Login1.UserName);
 if (username != null)
 {

     isUser = Membership.ValidateUser(username, Login1.Password);
   }
  if (isUser)
  {
     Login1.UserName = username;
      e.Authenticated = true;
   }
```

I am writing this code in the Login page. So after successful login, the loginview will update accordingly. Now it is working perfect. 
The answer given by **Win** also good one. If we want to show only email id in `LoginView` instead of user name we have to implement this method.

```
public string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
```

To get the user name by email we can write like

```
string username = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(Page.User.Identity.Name)
```